# SEARCH_LONG_PRESS in a broadcast not working?

Tags: android

This is not working. Any idea why I can not receive long search keypress?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".MainReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

MainReceiver.java

```
public class MainReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
      // Nothing comes here..   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys, i found the answer in the android documentation. It looks like Search button can not be used as a broadcast action. it is only an activity action.

> ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS      Activity
>   Action: Start action associated with
>   long pressing on the search key.